# Django4 формы связанные с моделью

Tags: python, django

Делаю форму обратной связи на сайте.

Для этого создана отдельная модель которая связана с моделью Users связью 1 ко многим.

Создаю форму с привязкой к модели.

При выводе в шаблон получаю пустой объект...

**models.py**

```
class Feedback(models.Model):
    User_send = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Пользователь')
    Messages = models.TextField(verbose_name='Обращение', null=True)
```

**views.py**

```
def feedback(request):
    if request.POST:
        feedback_form = Feedback(request.POST)
        if feedback_form.is_valid():
                feedback_Obj = feedback_form.save(commit=False)
                Us = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
                feedback_Obj.user = Us
                feedback_Obj.save()
                return redirect('myprofile')
    else:
        feedback_form = Feedback()
        return render(request, 'car/feedback.html', {'feedback_form': feedback_form})
```

**forms.py**

```
class Feedback(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Feedback
        fields = ['Messages']

        widgets = {
            'Messages': forms.TextInput(),
        }
```

**шаблон html**

```
{% extends 'car/base.html' %}

{% block carlist %}

    <form class="input-data" action="{% url 'feedback' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}

          {{ feedback_form }}</br>

        <button class="link-read-lot" type="submit">Отправить</button>
    </form>
{% endblock carlist %}
```

В браузере форма не появляется.

В консоли (через print().) вижу пустой объект формы...

[image: Выхлоп консоли]

вот так показано в браузере:

[image: Браузер]

Что делаю не так?

Comment: Ну так в показанном коде у вас нету никаких форм, `Feedback` это модель а не форма

Comment: @andreymal Простите забыл добавить =)
Исправил.

Comment: `Feedback` не может быть одновременно моделью и формой, он может быть чем-то одним. И судя по тому, что вы видите в print и в браузере — в вашем случае `Feedback` это модель

Comment: @andreymal Какая глупая ошибка (
Все заработало! 
Напишите ответ, я отмечу галочкой)